# Spring "alias is required"

Tags: spring, spring-security, alias

I'm new in Spring and I'm trying to create a application using Spring Blazeds Integration (Flex + Blazeds + Spring + Java) and when I run the application I got this error:

```
02:51:21,852 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml]
02:51:23,937 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: alias is required.
    Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml]
```

The security-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <security:http>
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:form-login default-target-url="/myContext/Index.html"
            login-page="/myContext/Login.html" />
        <security:remember-me key="myAppKey" services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="myAppKey" />
        <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="john" password="john" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <security:user name="guest" password="guest" authorities="ROLE_GUEST" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I'm using *spring-flex 1.5.0*, *spring-security 2.0.6* and *Spring 3.0*.

**Any ideas what is the problem?**

Thanks in advance,
Andre

Comment: Show us the full stack trace, not just the first couple of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed in the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/index.html#optional-system-requirements), Spring Flex 1.5.0 will not work with Spring Security 2. You must use Spring Security 3.

Other than this, jbbarquero is correct, assuming this is actually your problem.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for you answer. I download and configured the app with Spring-Security 3.0.0 and happens the same error that was happening with the version 3.0.5: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.Authentication`. I searched that problem and this happens because in Spring Security 3.0.x they changed the package of this class (now it is org.springframework.security.core.Authentication). Any idea how can I sove this?

Comment: Hi, I found the issues regarding ClassNotFoundException. There was an extra lib (**org.springframework.flex-1.5.0.CI-367**) apart from the spring-flex-core-1.5.0.RELEASE. After removing, it works fine!

Comment: Great! Yes, be careful not to mix versions of the same Spring project. And we can all be thankful that Jeremy finally released Spring Flex 1.5 :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure, but try to put an alias in ***security:authentication-manager***:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
```

Why don't you use Spring security 3?